# Sub menu showing behind slider in wordpress

Tags: css, revolution-slider

I am modifying a `wordpress blog`. I have added `revolution slider`, Now my `submenu` (Created from `Ubermenu`), showing behind revolution slider.

I have tried zindex 999 for menu, and revolution slider to zindex: -1.

Nothing works

Any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet.

```
.ubermenu .ubermenu-item.ubermenu-active .ubermenu-submenu-drop{
    z-index: 21;
}
```

The `li` inside the revolution slider has a z-index of 20. So, to display your sub-menu above that, find the exact HTML selector of the submenu using web inspector and increase its z-index value.

Answer (score 0):

element with id `rev_slider_2_1` should have `z-index:1;`

element with id `ubermenu-main-52-new-menu` should have `z-index:9999;`

Comment: I recommend using a more meaningful `z-index` value, as opposed to `9999`.